# Android app icon name picked from activity label than from application label

Tags: android, android-manifest

Not sure if anyone else posted this question, didn't find any, though there are similar ones.

This is my manifest xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
      android:name="com.listCalc.tutorial.simpleinappbillingv3.ui.StartUpActivity"
      android:label="@string/activity_startup_label"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
      android:name="com.listCalc.tutorial.simpleinappbillingv3.ui.MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/activity_main_label"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
      android:name="com.listCalc.tutorial.simpleinappbillingv3.ui.PurchasePassportActivity"
      android:label="@string/activity_purchase_label"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
  </application>
```

String.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <string name="app_name">List Calc in-app billing V3</string>
  <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
  <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
  <string name="main_button_purchase_passport_text">Purchase Passport</string>
  <string name="main_cont_desc_image_passport">purchased passport</string>
  <string name="activity_startup_label">Loading</string>
  <string name="activity_main_label">Main Menu</string>
  <string name="activity_purchase_label">Making Purchase</string>

</resources>
```

The application name i.e. the launcher icon name is being picked up as "activity_startup_label" and not "app_name"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post your string.xml data here also provide screenshot for better understanding

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Nothing. This is working as designed.

You are welcome to also have an `android:label` attribute on the `<intent-filter>`, which should be used for the launcher icon label, according to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#iconlabel):

> The icon and label set for an intent filter are used to represent a component whenever the component is presented to the user as fulfilling the function advertised by the filter. For example, a filter with "android.intent.action.MAIN" and "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" settings advertises an activity as one that initiates an application — that is, as one that should be displayed in the application launcher. The icon and label set in the filter are therefore the ones displayed in the launcher.

Comment: I dont know, but in my case it was still getting the `android:label` from the `<activity>` for the launcher icon label and using the one in the `<intent-filter>` just when I was desinstalling the app.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, you are the savior of Android Community.

Comment: so what is the point setting label in `application` if activity has label in it's root and in it's intent filter? I was assuming if I have label in `application` I won't have to use `label` in intent filter...

Comment: @deadfish: "so what is the point setting label in application" -- that is used in other places, such as the list of installed applications on the device, as shown in the Settings app. "I was assuming if I have label in application I won't have to use label in intent filter" -- you do not have to have a label in an `<intent-filter>`. You *can* have a label in an `<activity>` or in an `<intent-filter>` to override values set elsewhere (e.g., in `<application>`).

Comment: It used to be that only bad launchers used the activity label instead of the intent filter label, but now LauncherApps does as well. There is no longer any practical mechanism for having an icon label that's different from the initial window title.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think the solution is broken - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/61328477/2401535.

Comment: @MarianPaździoch: The behavior of any given launcher is up to the developers of the launcher, by and large. All you can do is fill in the manifest and hope for the best.

Comment: I dont know what launcher does emulator use but there it does not work as well. So - it does not work nowhere.

Comment: @MarianPaździoch: "it does not work nowhere" -- there are hundreds of launchers, both pre-installed and user-installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a "launcher activity" with [label name] & "application tag" also with a different [label name] then Android will take the [label name] from the Launcher Activity.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to the one proposed by Commonsware (which I've found to be hit and miss on some devices) is to set the label of the application in the manifest as you're doing, to *not* set the label of the launcher activity in the manifest and instead to set it programmatically in your activity's `onCreate(Bundle)` method as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle(R.string.activity_startup_label);
    // do whatever else you need to
}
```

Comment: Would be great to know why this answer was downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the label of the main activity is "activity_startup_label"

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest.xml change your label to:

```
    android:label="@string/app_name"
```